# Moving multiple levels bcak in linux

Tags: linux, command-line

i know `cd ..` takes you one level back from current directory, when i want to move two levels back from my current directory, I issued the command `cd ../ ../` but it isn't considering and I have been kept only one level back. What are the commands for moving multiple levels back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cd ../..` without spaces between `/` and `..`.